# If $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ with $a_n >0$ is convergent, then is $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt {a_n a_{n+1}} $ always convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ with $a_n >0$ is convergent. I am claiming that $\sqrt {a_n a_{n+1}} < a_n $ if possible let $\sqrt {a_n a_{n+1}} > a_n $ then $ a_n a_{n+1} > {a_n}^2 $ implies $ a_{n+1} > a_n $ implies $a_n$ is increasing,  a contradiction since $ a_n > 0 $ and $ \lim a_n =0$, so our assumption is wrong now using comparison test we can conclude that $\sqrt {a_n a_{n+1}} $ is always convergent.

Is my proof OK if not can you  give me a hint.

Comment: Your proof is not valid. Indeed, consider the example $$ a_n = \frac{1}{(n+(-1)^{n-1})^2}, \qquad (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, \cdots) = \left( \frac{1}{2^2}, \frac{1}{1^2}, \frac{1}{4^2}, \frac{1}{3^2}, \cdots \right). $$ It is clear that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_
n$ converges. But both $\sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} < a_n$ and $\sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} > a_n$ are possible depending on the parity of $n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Since $\sum a_n$ is a series of positive terms, you can commute them and suppose $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: @ÁngelValencia, Rearranging the terms will change the expression of $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$, and it rarely helps resolving the issue in OP's proof. To be specific, if $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection such that $b_n = a_{\sigma(n)}$ is decreasing, then we are forced to consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{b_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}b_{\sigma^{-1}(n+1)}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

By AM-GM inequality, we have

$$\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}} \le \frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}$$

Use comparison test afterward.

Comment: More generally, if $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\,a_n$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\,a^k_{n}a_{n+1}^{1-k}$ converges for all real numbers $k$ with $0<k<1$.

Comment: Carleman's inequality, that is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_1 \ldots a_k)^{1/k} \le \mathrm{e} \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$, is also an interesting variation of the initial inequality.

Comment: (+1) But in case the OP does not know about AM-GM in general: the inequality in this answer is  a direct consequence of  $u^2 + v^2 \ge  2 u v$, with $u$ and $v$ positive, which one gets from expanding and rearranging $(u- v)^2 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}} \leq \max(a_n, a_{n+1}) < a_n+a_{n+1}$$